# Using Beautiful Soup to parse Edabit - Python

Tags: python, meteor, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to write code to get the amount of XP obtained by completing Edabit's challenges by parsing the individual url associated with a user on the site. Here's what I have:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "https://edabit.com/user/xHRGAqa56TcXTLEMW"
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
div = soup.find(id="react-root")
print(div)
```

The find is returning a value of none but I really don't know why. I think the site was made with meteor and that may be causing a problem?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when there is dynamic content on the website which is then loaded when the javascript is executed in the browser.

You can look at the page source of your webpage in browser to see if the tag is there or not.

Since your script is not a browser but just a program which is fetching the webpage from the website, that's why the content is not being showed in your script.

If you want that javascript to be executed in the script you can setup something like [`splash`](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) server.

Another way would be to check the network requests that javascript is making in your browser to load that content(which is usually an API request) and make those same requests to get the content from the API directly instead of crawling it from the browser.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

there is none output means soup.find didn't match any id that you searched for. Inspect the html file once again correctly. It may work.